# Amazon S3 upload file with java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to amazon s3 and im getting 403 error, tried to follow an example provoded by amazon [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html) here is my code:

```
public boolean uploadFile() {
    BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(id, secret);
    try {
        AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials))
                .build();
        client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, uploadFileName, this.file));
        return true;
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
                "means your request made it " +
                "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
                " for some reason.");
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        return false;
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which " +
                "means the client encountered " +
                "an internal error while trying to " +
                "communicate with S3, " +
                "such as not being able to access the network.");
        System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

What I was given by my client is the bucket, the id and the secret. If anyone could point out what i'm doing wrong and point me to some example I could look into. I'm new to amazon aws.

Comment: I would first use the awscli to validate that you can upload to that bucket with the provided credentials. Then debug your code. If you're unable to upload via awscli then go back to the client to verify the credentials.

Comment: as you said the problem were the credentials there were wrong! Thanks on the help @jarmod

Answer (score 0):

It was a credential problem the id and the secret weren't working